# Работа с Dll C#

Tags: c#

### Собственно такая проблема:

---

> есть dll, которая подключена к
> проекту. Затем происходят опред.
> действия и после чего эту dll нужно
> заменить на другую, но ведь dll
> задействована проектом, каким образом
> можно это сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это сложно, на самом деле. Ответ сильно зависит от того, используете ли вы нативную DLL и подключаете её для P/Invoke, или это .NET Assembly.

Для первого случая есть два простых похода:

Первый подход: вместо прямого P/Invoke c атрибутом `DllImport` (который соответствует статической линковке) вы пользуетесь динамической линковкой через `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`. Для этого неплохо завести обёртку:

```
abstract class DynamicDllFunctions : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

    IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    public DynamicDllFunctions(string filename)
    {
        Handle = LoadLibrary(filename);
        if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Exception(
               string.Format("Failed to load library (ErrorCode: {0})", errorCode));
        }
    }

    protected GetDelegate<T>(string functionName)
    {
        IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(Handle, functionName);
        return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<T>(funcaddr);
        // или для старых версий .NET
        // return (T)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcaddr, typeof(T));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            FreeLibrary(Handle);
    }
}

class PluginFunctions : DynamicDllFunctions
{
    public PluginFunctions(string filename) : base(filename)
    {
        GetPluginHealthImpl = GetDelegate<GetPluginHealthDelegate>("GetPluginHealth");
    }

    delegate bool GetPluginHealthDelegate();
    GetPluginHealthDelegate GetPluginHealthImpl;
    public bool GetPluginHealth()
    {
        return GetPluginHealthImpl();
    }
}
```

Второй подход — избавиться от P/Invoke и сделать всё то же в модуле на C++/CLI.

---

Для случая с .NET-assembly всё сложнее, так как CLR в .NET Framework никогда не выгружает однажды загруженную assembly. Это ограничение, однако, можно обойти таким способом: заведите отдельный `AppDomain`, в который загружайте динамические DLL. В нём можно вполне нормально грузить DLL-ки при помощи `Assembly.Load`. При необходимости выгрузить DLL вы выгружаете весь `AppDomain`, и создаёте новый. Кроме этого, вам придётся наладить маршаллирование между `AppDomain`-ами, так что задача не такая уж лёгкая.

А вот .NET Core 3.0+ возможность выгружать загруженные сборки появилась. `AppDomain`-ы там, правда, не поддерживаются в полной мере, зато вы сэкономите на достаточно сложном маршаллировании. Вам придётся создать специальный [`AssemblyLoadContext`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=netcore-3.1), загружать в него ваши библиотеки, и когда понадобиться выгрузит, убедиться, что вы не ссылаетесь нигде на код из библиотеки (в частности, что код этой библиотеки не выполняется в фоновом потоке). Полный пример — [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability). 
А специально для вашего случая есть ещё немного информации: [*Create a .NET Core application with plugins*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support).

Дерзайте!

Comment: @JPro: добавил недостающую функцию `GetProcAddress`.

---
Пожалуйста!

Comment: как правильно загружать нативную библиотеку враппер, которая грузит `jvm.dll` и потом `jar `

Comment: @hellboy: Даже не знаю, ни разу не пробовал. А что за библиотека? Думаю, имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @VladD А что будет если сослаться на тип, который был выгружен из AssemblyLoadContext? Исключение? А что будет если тип внутри себя запускает поток, а потом инициировать выгрузку. Приложение убьет поток при выгрузке и продолжит корректно работать?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Сослаться невозможно, т. к. тип недоступен при компиляции (мы ж грузим библиотеку динамически). Но если у нас бежит поток, то существует экземпляр типа, который находится в выгружаемой сборке. Тогда сборка не будет выгружена до тех пор, пока этот экземпляр не съест сборщик мусора.

Comment: @iluxa1810: То есть приложение не убьёт поток, наоборот, это наша ответственность его завершить, иначе библиотека не выгрузится.

Comment: @VladD Хм... Я думал, что можно запускать небезопасный код, как в доменах этим способом, что бы, скажем, если код не вырубается по TimeOut'у в сторонней либе, то можно прибить... Получается, что в .NET CORE остается с подобным небезопасным кодом работать через IPC?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Да, с небезопасным кодом надо работать через IPC. Проблема была даже в .NET Framework. Попробуйте, например, выгрузить домен, в котором выполняется такой код: `try {} finally { while (true) { } }`. Код из `finally` не получится прервать, так что домен не выгрузится. // Поэтому небезопасный код нельзя пускать в свой процесс.