# Как при использовании DllImport передать строку

Tags: c#, c, строки, dll, преобразование

Доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь использовать libshout.dll. При указании параметров методу возникает ошибка. Неправильно работаю со строками. Как передать **string** в метод который принимает **char ***

```
[DllImport("libshout-3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int shout_set_host(long instance, string host);
```

Сам метод на Си:

```
int shout_set_host(shout_t *self, const char *host)
```

Что интересно. я понял как правильно получить строку в методе который возвращает **char ***:

```
[DllImport("libshout-3.dll" , CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]       
internal static extern IntPtr shout_get_error(long instance);

//вот так преобразовываем в строку
return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(shout_get_error(this.instance))
```

Comment: P.S. в методах которые принимают int всё проходит нормально. Значит явно с преобразованием строк надо что-то делать

Comment: Надо понимать что 1. c# использует Unicode. нужно перевести его в ASCII byte[], 2. не в ASCII a в ACSIIz. и передать ссылку на массив.

Comment: что такое ACSIIz ? Я никак не пойму как всё это отправить правильно.

Comment: гугл разблокировали и я прочитал про ACSIIz. сделал так 
 byte[] retArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(host);
 byte[] retArrayZ = new byte[retArray.Length + 1];
 Не помогло. все равно не выполняется корректно метод

Comment: ASCIIZ заканчивается нулём, `GetBytes(host + '\0')` как минимум (так правильнее, new byte - вам даст чисто нули ). По идее должно быть "стандартное" преобразование, я его не знаю. По идее можно поискать импорт того же kernel32.dll там много ANSI-функций

Comment: Попробуйте так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/310479/17974

Comment: Вместо `CharSet.Unicode` нужно задать `CharSet.Ansi`. Также можно попробовать `ChaSet.Auto`.

Comment: Возможно, нужно у параметра `host` задать атрибут [MarshalAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). И подобрать `UnmanagedType`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CharSet = CharSet.Unicode
> ```
>
> ```
> const char *host
> ```

Ну очевидно же, что не сочетается. Нужно в однобайтовой кодировке передавать:

```
CharSet = CharSet.Ansi
```